# Can mobile Stack Overflow have a link to meta in the footer?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, mobile-web, per-site-meta

So meta has a link to the main site in its footer, but there is currently no way to get to meta from the main site short of editing the URL yourself (not cool on a mobile).

As noted in [the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121391/can-mobile-stack-overflow-have-a-link-to-meta-in-the-footer#comment321589_121391), all the other sites have a link to their meta in the footer, so it only seems to be SO that's missing out.

Comment: Oddly enough I edited the URL in my address bar to go back to the main site when I first spotted this question on the front page.

Comment: Interestingly enough, all other sites have it.

Comment: @BoltClock: it's more frustrating when you get the urge to hit meta from within a question. You either have to trim the lonnnng question title from the URL, retype the whole URL or don't bother at the expense of a 404 and then hit the logo from the top... scroll, scroll click would be much easier ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed that was an oversight. Fixed in the next build.